# What is the integral ∫x(t)dt

Tags: physics, classical-mechanics, euler-lagrange-equation

I am learning classical physics using the Lagrangian and came across a problem when solving an example.

Suppose you have a spring system, where:

$KE = \frac{1}{2}m(\dot{x})^{2}$

$\ \ \ \ \ and$

$PE = \frac{1}{2}kx^{2}$

The Lagrangian of the system is therefore:


$L \equiv T-U$

$L = \frac{1}{2}m(\dot{x})^{2}-\frac{1}{2}kx^{2}$


Using the Euler-Lagrange equation we can calculate the equation of motion,

$\frac{d}{dt}(\frac{∂L}{∂\dot{x}})=\frac{∂L}{∂x}$


We get,

$m\ddot{x}=-kx$


Therefore, acceleration $\ddot{x}$ must be -$\frac{kx}{m}$


If we integrate the differential equation to solve for the velocity, we get


$\dot{x}=-\frac{k}{m}\int{x}dt$


Here arises my confusion:
How would one integrate $x(t)$ in respect to $t$, if $x(t) =\int{\dot{x}dt}$ or $\ddot{x}$ integrated twice in respect to time


$or$


$-\frac{k}{m}\int{x}dt = -\frac{k}{m}xt$

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly you're asking. Are you trying to solve the differential equation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$m\ddot{x}=-kx\implies \int m(\dot{x}\ddot{x})dt=\int -kx\dot{x}dt$

$m\dot{x}^2/2=-kx^2/2+C$

Worth noting $C$ is a constant of motion, the total energy.

$\dot{x}=\sqrt{2C-kx^2}/\sqrt{m}$

$\frac{dx}{\sqrt{(2C-kx^2)/m}}=dt$

Integrate both sides, the left using trig substitution. Can you take it from there?